# Grails: Custom constraint on class made Validateable not working

Tags: validation, grails

I have a class `Report` made validateable by adding it to the `grails.validateable.classes` property of Config.groovy:

```
class Report {

    /* fields */
    Product product

    static constraints = {
        product nullable: true, validator: { val ->
            if(val && val.quantity > 0) {
                return (val.code && val.locations.size() > 0)
            }
        }
    }
}

class Product {
    BigDecimal quantity
    String code
    List<Location> locations
}
```

With that, I try validating a `Report` by calling `report.validate()` however `validate` always returns true. I tried making the custom validator:

```
...
product validator: { val ->
    return false
}
```

so that calling `validate` on a `Report` always returns false but it still returns true making the instance valid. As far as I can tell, custom validators on classes made Validateable are not called when calling `validate`.

Is this a known bug? I can't find a reference anywhere if it is. Can't I use custom validators for classes that are made Validateable? Or something is wrong with my code?

**Edit**: Fixed typo. Should be `grails.validateable.classes` instead of `grails.validateable.class`

Comment: Is there a typo in your question on `grails.validateable.class`(misses `es`)? In Config.groovy, it is something like `grails.validateable.classes = [com.mycompany.myapp.User, com.mycompany.dto.Account]`.

Comment: Yes. That's a typo. Sorry bout that.

Comment: see if http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14235304/grails-constraint-for-service-callback-property-needs-capital-first-letter/14255081#14255081 helps.

Comment: Had no luck with the linked answer. :(